# How to migrate git repositories from Azure DevOps to GitHub

Tags: github, azure-devops, tfs

How to **migrate** git repositories from Azure DevOps Repositories to GitHub ?

Answer (score 0):

There is dedicated [GitHub CLI extension](https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/using-github-enterprise-importer/migrating-repositories-with-github-enterprise-importer/migrating-repositories-from-azure-devops-to-github-enterprise-cloud) that can generate script for doing migration of repositories, and also using one of the CLI parameters to update all Azure DevOps pipelines to edit their definition to check out code from GitHub instead of Azure repository. One of the case where we can find issue it that when we have custom task in Azure DevOps pipeline that is doing code check out not in standard way for example. For example, task doing code checkout using command line.